# Premature end of file in solr

Tags: solr

I got the  Error and I have writen this xml. what wrong in this?

> CREATEing SolrCore 'blog': Unable to create core [blog] Caused by:
>   Premature end of file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
    <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_36</luceneMatchVersion>
    <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true" />
    <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />
    <requestHandler name="/admin" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
    <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
        <lst name="invariants">
            <str name="qt">search</str>
            <str name="q"></str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
</config>
```

Comment: Could you post the error from Solr logs?

Comment: premature end of file indicates your XML file was not complete, check all your xml files have proper tag

Comment: I have 2 xml files one is schema.xml and other one is solrconfig.xml  solr config i have gave you and schema.xml is empty